# Extract Google's first pages' all href links of any keywords listed in Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

I tried to fetch all the href links after Google page loads of that particular keyword.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private chr As Selenium.ChromeDriver

Sub Test()
Dim i As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
For i = 2 To lastrow
    Dim mykeyword As String
    mykeyword = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value
    Set chr = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    chr.Start
    chr.Get "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & mykeyword
    chr.Wait 1000

    Dim Mylinks As Selenium.WebElements
    Dim Mylink As Selenium.WebElement

    Set Mylinks = chr.FindElementsByCss("div.yuRUbf.a")

    For Each Mylink In Mylinks
        If LCase(Mylink.Attribute("data-ved")) = "2ahUKEwjSuvfI1MP9AhWu-TgGHRNrAB4QFnoECAkQAQ" Then
            Debug.Print Mylink.Attribute("href")
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Mylink
    If i = lastrow Then
        chr.Quit
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

The macro is taking all the keywords also from the Excel sheet, but it is not fetching the href links as expected.

I tried to run this for this keyword just for an instance "608-2Z site:fagbearing.cc AND filetype:pdf" and that opened the link also i.e.

```
"https://www.google.com/search?q=608-2Z+site%3Afagbearing.cc+AND+filetype%3Apdf&rlz=1C1JJTC_enIN1044IN1044&oq=608-2Z+site%3Afagbearing.cc+AND+filetype%3Apdf&aqs=chrome.0.69i59.735j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8"
```

and after that, it needed to fetch these two resulting links that come after loading but it didn't.

1. https://www.fagbearing.cc/PDF-bearings/SKF-Rolling-Bearings-PDF.pdf
2. https://www.fagbearing.cc/PDF-bearings/KOYO-Ball-Roller-Bearings-PDF.pdf...

Answer (score 0):

This code works as far as it goes ...

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim chr As ChromeDriver
    Set chr = New ChromeDriver
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim mykeyword As String
    Dim MyLinks As WebElements
    Dim MyLink As WebElement
    Dim sFilename As String
    
    sFilename = "C:\Users\<username>\Downloads\log-" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmddHHMMSS") & ".txt"
    Open sFilename For Output As #1
    Print #1, "START"
    Print #1, Now()
    lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set chr = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    Call chr.Start("edge")
    chr.Get ("https://www.google.com")
    chr.FindElementById("L2AGLb").Click ' L2AGLb Accept all
    chr.Window.Maximize
    chr.Wait 1000
    For i = 2 To lastrow
     mykeyword = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value
     chr.Get ("https://www.google.com/search?q=" & mykeyword)
     Set MyLinks = chr.FindElementsByTag("a")
     chr.Wait 1000
     Print #1, "Start"
     Print #1, mykeyword
     Print #1, MyLinks.Count
     For Each MyLink In MyLinks
 '      If LCase(MyLink.Attribute("data-ved")) = "2ahUKEwjSuvfI1MP9AhWu-TgGHRNrAB4QFnoECAkQAQ" Then
              Print #1, "href = " & MyLink.Attribute("href")
              Print #1, "data-ved = " & MyLink.Attribute("data-ved")
 '        Exit For
 '      End If
      Next MyLink
      chr.Wait 1000
      'If i = lastrow Then
      ' chr.Quit
      'End If
     Next i
     Print #1, "End ***"
     Close #1
End Sub
```

There was a strange problem with using Debug.Print so I changed to use a text file as output.

It was necessary for me to click the Accept cookies banner first before searching for keywords.

The code then finds plenty of "a" tags with an href attribute, not all of them have data-ved attributes.

The MyLink.Attribute("data-ved") = "2ahUKEwjSuvfI1MP9AhWu-TgGHRNrAB4QFnoECAkQAQ" is never found in the pages that I saw.

I used the keywords "a", "b" and "c" to search.

I used the VBA type library that Microsoft support

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/

I used MS Edge - the Selenium version must match the version of Edge that you have installed.

Edge Version 110.0.1587.57

You will need to browse to the type library for your machine either 32 or 64 bit.

Tools > References > Selenium Type Library (Selenium64.tlb)

Comment: Thank you so much, it is working out. But is it possible to filter out only those href links that are there in the google's sourced page. Thats's the only things i was in need of. They also have unique class name for them through which we can separate out them and get only them as our results .i.e. class="yuRUbf". And those href links also have another unique identifier with it's attribute value "data-ved=" begins with "2ahUKE" and ends with "QAQ". Please advise is it possible to fetch only them as our result.

Comment: There are no links with class="yuRUbf"

Comment: Try with this code `Mid(sDataVed, 1, 6) = "2ahUKE"`

Comment: Thank you, Using mid function, i can filter only those results  that i want, but what if i need only those href links that exist in the first page of the google's number of page results.

Comment: Thank You user10186832... Can anybody help with what is that we need to be changed in the code if i need the links that are coming only in the first page of google results. It would be of great help. Thank you:-)