# How to fetch data from a cell or range of cells and put it into Sendkeys with the correct parameters and arguments. To input into a webpage box

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys, findelement

Here is the Excel VBA code I have so far that opens Microsoft Edge:

```
Dim obj As New WebDriver

Sub testEdgeAuto()

obj.Start "edge", ""
obj.Get "https://www.redfin.com"

obj.FindElementByName("searchInputBox").SendKeys
```

For the Sendkeys, I can input an address value, and on the webpage it will populate the search box with it. What I would like to do is have SendKeys fetch either the value from a cell or a range of cells and input them in the search box. Suggestions? Thanks!

Don't know the parameters and arguments of sendkeys on how to do that.

Comment: Why are you using `SendKeys`? There are much more reliable ways of doing this. Which tutorial are you using to learn from?

Comment: Some YouTube videos on Excel VBA. If you have a more elegant and sufficient solution, I would be grateful if you would share it. Thank you!

Comment: Are you required to do this in Excel VBA for some reason? It's not very well documented or supported. If not, I would choose a different language like C#, Java, python, etc. that has [Selenium bindings](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/#bindings) and start there.

Comment: This code works for Google ...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75639935/extract-googles-first-pages-all-href-links-of-any-keywords-listed-in-our-excel/75644808#75644808

Comment: This answer works for me  ...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75923317/which-webpage-element-is-the-proper-one-for-findelementby/75938502#75938502